# jQuery Mobile links issue

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with jQuery Mobile. I am using PhoneGap.

When i click on any internal link (such as #page1),
jQuery doesn't load it internally, but opens the Mobile Browser and loads it there.

In addition, pages scroll does not work initially - you cannot scroll down the page. (in the app, not in the opened browser)

Only when you click a link in the app, goes out of the app and then return to the app,
it is all fixed - the internal links and the scroll.

Looks like jQuery JS does not load as it should...

Does anyone know this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What device are you having these issues on?

Comment: What version of Android?

Comment: Yeah if you are using Android 4.0 there appears to be a bug with urls with # in them for the web view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load your html file in [Ripple](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple) and see if there's any Javascript error on the execution with PhoneGap. I had a similar problem and I found it with that program.

Comment: Ok, thanks, really good. But did anyone bump into this problem ever?